# How to increase spacing between dt tags

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to increase the spacing between these dt tags through css here is my html

```
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content">

        <d1 id ="contact-info"><dt><h2>FIND OUT MORE ABOUT US</h2></dt>
          <dt><h2>AND OUR SERVICES:</h2></dt>

         <dt><h1>CLX Exchange Accommodators, Inc.</h1></dt>

          <dt>970 Main Avenue</dt>
         <dt>Durango, CO 81301</dt>
         <dt>(877) 776-1031 </dt>
         <dt>(970) 247-5464</dt>
         <dt>FAX (970) 247-0105</dt>
           <dt>E-mail: info@1031clx.com</dt>
        </d1>
      </div>
      <!--End of content -->
      <div id="footer">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="whatIs1031.html">What is a 1031 Exchange?</a></li>
            <li><a href="exchangeRequ.html">
               1031 Exchange Requirements</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="typesOfExchange.html">Types of Exchanges</a></li>
            <li><a href="howToStart.html">How to get Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="whyCLX.html">Why CLX?</a></li>
            <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="fAQs.html">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="fees.html">Fees</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!--end of footer -->
   </div>
   <!--End of Wrapper -->
```

I've tried changing contact-info to display block, because I firgued display in-line issue but I most of been wrong. I have also tried to modify both the padding and margin of the elements and there seems to be no effect.

And here is my code on codepen http://cdpn.io/hAJyF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a css rule for the dt tag:

```
#contact-info dt{

}
```

In the rule you can specify a padding or margin to increase the space between them. Alternatively you can add a `<br />` between them to add a blank line.

This does beg the question though as to why you are using a dt tag there at all.

Comment: What html element would you suggest then?

Comment: The `address` tag is meant for expressing contact information (not necessarily restricted to addresses like the tag name implies).

Comment: You don't need to wrap each line in any tag, just use a <br/> to break the line. I would wrap each section in a <div> though. As a side note you seem to have a d1 tag (d followed by the number 1), the correct tags is dl (d followed by the letter l).

Comment: I just added the break lines between the elements